# Retain session between PHP HTTP Requests in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, session-cookies

I recently started setting up PhpStorm with Xdebug and so far running and debugging scripts works perfectly.

Now I want to debug a script which requires the user to be logged in (by a PHP session). My initial idea was to create a separate PHP HTTP Request logging the user in. The problem is that the PHP session is not retained between PHP HTTP Requests, so `$_SESSION` is always empty.

Do you have any idea why this happens (my guess is that the session cookie doesn't get stored) and how do I fix this?

Additional information:

- The web server is running on a Linux machine on my local network.
- I'm using PHP 7.1, PhpStorm 2018.2.2 and Xdebug 2.6.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start your test by  logging in as normal, then go via the normal system flow to the script you want to test

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not testing the script using my browser. Instead i'm using the PHP HTTP Request run configuration. - The reason I don't use my browser (Opera) is that the plugin isn't available, but if you have an idea on how to debug with it, I'd love to try it.

Comment: How about just setting `$_SESSION` manually while debugging? `$_SESSION = array('x', 'y', 'z')`

Comment: @FrankerZ That's what I'm currently doing. It works, but it would be easier without having to add debugging code.

Comment: If you have session ... then you should have a session cookie. I do not think that this kind of Run/Debug Configuration supports it (cookies). Try RESTful services: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/editor-based-rest-client/ or just use Postman (or alike) to send your request -- just add Xdebug cookie (or GET/POST param) to the request. I sometimes debug such specific requests and doing it with Postman (although in general I still prefer extra click (repetition) in browser -- a bit safer / old habit).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible using *Run/Debug Configurations* nor using the *HTTP Client* with .http files.

The solution is to use the *deprecated* REST Client under **Tools > HTTP Client > Test RESTful Web Service**. There you can set the PHP session cookie manually by navigating to the tab **Cookies**, clicking the plus on the right and copying the values from your browser.

Copy the PHP session cookie by right clicking your page in your browser, clicking **Inspect page** and navigating to the tab **Application**, in the left menu select **Cookies** then click on your server address and copy the information of the cookie with name **PHPSESSID** (or your custom cookie name specified in your servers *php.ini*).

A feature request for cookies in the HTTP Client is already subitted [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40381).

Hope this helps. *-Minding*